# Importing css/style files in .elm files with (or without) webpack

Tags: css, styling, elm

Can css/sass/stylus files be directly imported into Elm files in some way? The webpack `css-loader` module makes this possible in Javascript with an `import './styles.css'`, but I can't find anything on how one might do it in Elm with or without Webpack.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question when I started looking into styles and I ended up making a POC of how that might look like by using Elm port and subscriptions to tell Webpack to fetch CSS modules.

Check it out: https://github.com/geekyme/elm-css-modules

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done directly, but you can create a bridging entry point for Webpack that will import everything, including CSS and Elm together, for bundling.

Check this out: http://www.elm-tutorial.org/050_starting/webpack.html#indexjs

Comment: Link is broken.